# Gson can not parse nested string object

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, gson

How to parse  nested object

```
 [{
       "id": 100500,
       "products": "[{\"id\":45,\"title\":\"All Product\"]"
    }]
```

Model Class

```
public class Store {
      public  long id;
      public  List<Product> products;

}
```

Comment: I solve with replace string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi change you Gson to

```
{
  "Id": "100500",
  "products": [

      {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "title 1"
      },
      {
         "id": 2,
         "title": "title 2"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
          "title": "title 3"
      } 

  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No it will parse

```
public class Store {
      public  long id;
      public  List<Product> products;

}

Gson mGson= new Gson();
storeList=mGson.fromJson(json, Store.class);
storeList.getStores().get(0).getProducts().get(1);
```